# Code stopped working, didn't change a thing. Error is: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commands')

Tags: javascript, command, handler

When i run 'node .' in the terminal it produces this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commands')
```

This is strange as I haven't changed anything, I simply just came back to my work.

This is the Commands.js file :

```
const { Perms } = require("../Validation/Permissions");
const { Client } = require("discord.js");


/**
* @param {Client} Client
*/
module.exports = async (client, PG, Ascii) => {
const Table = new Ascii("Command Loaded");

CommandsArray = [];

(await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Commands/*/*.js`)).map(async (file) => {
    const command = require(file);

    if(!command.name)
    return Table.addRow(file.split("/")[7], "⛔ FAILED", "Missing a 
 name.")

    if(!command.context && !command.description)
    return Table.addRow(command.name, "⛔ FAILED", "Missing a 
 description.")

    if(command.permission) {
        if(Perms.includes(command.permission))
        command.defaultPermission = false;
        else
        return Table.addRow(command.name, "⛔ FAILED", "Permission is 
 invalid.")
    }

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    CommandsArray.push(command);
    
    await Table.addRow(command.name, "✔ SUCCESSFUL");

 });

 console.log(Table.toString());

 // Permissions Check //

 client.on("ready", async () => {
    const MainGuild = await          
 client.guilds.cache.get("961963167410454598");

        MainGuild.commands.set(CommandsArray).then(async (command) => 
 {
            const Roles = (commandName) => {
                const cmdPerms = CommandsArray.find((c) => c.name === 
 commandName).permission;
                if(!cmdPerms) return null;

                return MainGuild.roles.cache.filter((r) => 
 r.permissions.has(cmdPerms));
            }


            const fullPermissions = command.reduce((accumulator, r)
      => {
                const roles = Roles(r.name);
                if(!roles) return accumulator;

                const permissions = roles.reduce((a, r) => {
                    return [...a, {id: r.id, type: "ROLE", 
 permission: true}]
                }, [])

                return [...accumulator, {id: r.id, permissions}]
            }, [])

            await MainGuild.commands.permissions.set({ 
 fullPermissions });
        });

        });

   }
```

The full error is :

```
C:\Users\wrigh\Documents\Discord Bots\Practice Bot - 
Copy\Structures\Handlers\Commands.js:43
        MainGuild.commands.set(CommandsArray).then(async (command) => 
{
```

It's line 43, or just under // Permissions Check // if you can't find it.
Any help is appreciated.

Again there have been no changes except uploading it to github, this is when i realised it stopped working.

Sorry about the format of the code, it got messed up when i pasted it in.

If you need to look at any other files please just ask!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include your code and errors as text and not as links and explain what you did to make it stop working.  Links to source code do not stand to the test of time (as they expire or are broken, which makes the question with no context).

Comment: Okay sorry, this is my first time using SourceCode, and now can't make questions for a week because of the negative feedback :( 

I will do better next time.

Comment: That's Ok.   We all live and learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access an attribute of an object (ex. object.userName) and it's undefined, you should console log out the entire object, and see if that property even exists on the object, or if the entire object is undefined as well.

From that point, if the client object does not have the property you're looking for, or if it is undefined itself, you can trace your issue down further from there.

I appreciate you uploading your code, but typically you want to have the code embedded into your question itself so we can run it there and inspect it properly.

Comment: Hi, sorry it's my first time using stackoverflow, im fairly some what new to coding.

I just edited the question i hope it's better.

Comment: Much better. Now, if you console log out the parent object what do you get? is the command attribute present on the object when logged to the console?

Comment: Thank you for the help, but i seemed to have fixed it. 

I changed: 

        await client.guilds.cache.get("YourID");

to

        await client.guilds.fetch("YourID");

I think this is because the guild wasn't cached but i'm still learning and I definitely have a long way to go.

Comment: You're very welcome, good luck!